# FullSimplify not finding trig substitution with other terms present

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Consider the following:

```
FullSimplify[Cos[x - y - z] + Cos[x + y + z] + 1]
```

Mathematica simply returns the exact expression with no simplification. However, if I instead write

```
FullSimplify[Cos[x - y - z] + Cos[x + y + z]]
```

I get

```
2 Cos[x] Cos[y + z]
```

How can I get Mathematica to recognize that the first two terms in the first expression can be combined? It seems that the addition of an extra term prevents Mathematica from finding a proper simplification.

Addendum:

Here is a more complex case which Mathematica is still struggling to simplify

```
Cos[1/4 (x - 2 y - z)] + Cos[1/4 (x + 2 y - z)] + Cos[(x + z)/4]
```

which should reduce to

```
2 Cos[y/2] Cos[(x - z)/4] + Cos[(x + z)/4]
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is using `ComplexityFunction` to make MMA treat `Plus` as more expensive than, e.g. `Times` (if you know in advance that answer should not contain `Plus`):

```
FullSimplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> (100 Count[#, _Plus] + LeafCount[#] &)]
```

that gives

```
1 + 2 Cos[x] Cos[y + z]
```

**EDIT**

Next is very clumsy, but we may apply `FullSimplify` on parts of expression and see what is the `LeafCount` of the result.

```
expr = Cos[1/4 (x - 2 y - z)] + Cos[1/4 (x + 2 y - z)] + Cos[(x + z)/4]
subs=Subsets[expr,{2,3}]
compl=Complement[expr,#]&/@subs
MinimalBy[Thread[expr[[0]]@@{FullSimplify[subs],compl}],LeafCount]
```

And we get

```
{2 Cos[y/2] Cos[(x - z)/4] + Cos[(x + z)/4]}.
```

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this capability. However it is still failing to simplify some stuff, I edited my post with a more complex example

Answer (score 0):

Try `TrigExpand`

```
TrigExpand[Cos[x - y - z] + Cos[x + y + z] + 1 ]
(*1 + 2 Cos[x] Cos[y] Cos[z] - 2 Cos[x] Sin[y] Sin[z]*)
```